# How to set https to one nginx and one docker nginx on one server

Tags: docker, nginx

I have one nginx and one docker nginx on one server.

I already setup a Https server (port is 80) at one nginx success,

I open `https://subdomain1.domain`, it will show web page success.

but I setup docker nginx https (port is 8080) fail.

I open `https://subdomain2.domain:8080`, it will show error below.

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
subdomain2.domain sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

This is my docker process information.

```
root@server:~/# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
c798c72861fa        13b3                "/bin/bash /app/dock…"   13 days ago         Up 16 minutes       443/tcp, 8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   nginx
```

And I have 4 nginx conf, I don't know how to adjust nginx conf to make docker https work.

1. in host  `/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`  below.

   ```
    user  www www;

    worker_processes auto;
    worker_cpu_affinity auto;

    error_log  /home/wwwlogs/nginx_error.log  crit;

    pid        /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;

    #Specifies the value for maximum file descriptors that can be opened by this process.
    worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

    events
    {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 51200;
        multi_accept off;
        accept_mutex off;
    }


    http
        {
            include       mime.types;
            default_type  application/octet-stream;

            server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
            client_header_buffer_size 32k;
            large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
            client_max_body_size 50m;

            sendfile on;
            sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
            tcp_nopush on;

            keepalive_timeout 60;

            tcp_nodelay on;

            fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

            gzip on;
            gzip_min_length  1k;
            gzip_buffers     4 16k;
            gzip_http_version 1.1;
            gzip_comp_level 2;
            gzip_types     text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml application/xml+rss;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
            gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";

            #limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m;
            ##If enable limit_conn_zone,add "limit_conn perip 10;" to server section.

            server_tokens off;
            access_log off;

    include vhost/*.conf;
    }
   ```
2. in host `/usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/subdomain1.domain.conf`

   ```
    server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name _;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        return 301;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 default ssl http2;
        server_name _;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/server.key;
        return 302;
    }


    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name subdomain1.domain;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/server.key;
        index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm default.php;
        root /home/wwwroot/default/[project name]/backstage;
        include rewrite/other.conf;
        include enable-php-pathinfo.conf;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$ {
           expires 30d;
        }  

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
           expires 12h;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
           allow all;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
           deny all;
        }

        access_log /home/wwwlogs/www.xxxx.com.log;
        error_log /home/wwwlogs/www.xxxx.error.log;
   }
   ```
3. in docker `/etc/nginx/conf.d/[appName].conf`

   ```
   server {
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1k;
        gzip_buffers 4 16k;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css application/xml text/javascript application/x-httpd-php image/jpeg image/gif image/png;
        gzip_vary off;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        client_max_body_size 200m;

        root    /app/dist;
        index   index.html;

        location /api/ {
                rewrite         /api/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass      https://localhost:8000/;
        }

        listen              443 ssl http2;
        server_name         subdomain2.domain;
        ssl_certificate     /app/nginx/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /app/nginx/server.key;


        #enable ssl
        ssl                       on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers      "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";


     }
   ```
4. in docker `/app/nginx/[appName].conf`

   ```
    server {
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1k;
        gzip_buffers 4 16k;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css application/xml text/javascript application/x-httpd-php image/jpeg image/gif image/png;
        gzip_vary off;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        client_max_body_size 200m;

        root    /app/dist;
        index   index.html;

        location /api/ {
                rewrite         /api/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass      https://localhost:8000/;
        }

        listen              443 ssl http2;
        server_name         subdomain2.domain;
        ssl_certificate     /app/nginx/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /app/nginx/server.key;


        #enable ssl
        ssl                       on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers      "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
        ;

     }

     server {
        listen 8080 ;
        server_name subdomain2.domain;
        return 308 https://$server_name$request_uri;
     }
   ```

How to fix subdomain2.domain https setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Stop nginx service in host
2. Build new container nginx again and expose port 443 to the host.

`docker run -d --name containter_name -p 8080:443  image`

then access: https://subdomain2.domain:8080

You should copy ssl_certificate and key to the container

Comment: root@server:~/# docker run -d --name new_nginx_container -p 443:443 -p 8080:8080 13b3
d01ab13577f2993ebbceaaea78fdf59cc1a002ade4553e05824bb4d91aea5ac5
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint new_nginx_container (25b3eacb34b3b7f7be43dcbae639b427c1f89d08563e3e849bb3ae28af4704b4): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use.

I already use 443 on host nginx, how to fix it?

Comment: there is  service that is listeing on port 443, stop it and build again

Comment: I can't stop service listening on port 443, I need it to run https://subdomain1.domain .